# Can't hover <tr>

Tags: jquery, html

I've got a table displaying some data. When hovering a row that row is highlighted (for various reasons I do this by adding a class with jQuery).

Now the problem is that in 1-2px between table cells the hover don't work. I've checked in the webkit inspector and it seams like the whole table is "triggered" between the cells not the tr.

I got some padding in the td's but no margins so that shouldn't be the problem?

Any suggestions?

**Update**

None of the following seam to work: `cellspacing="0"` on the `<table>`, `border-spacing: 0;` or  `border-collapse: collapse;` on the CSS.

Comment: a minimal code sample would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Add `cellspacing="0"` to the `<table>` (or `border-spacing: 0;` to the CSS).

Answer (score 1):

Or add `border-collapse: collapse;` to the table's CSSs.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting:

```
table
{
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

This is the CSS equivalent of the old "cellspacing" attribute on the table.